# Gnuplot last point in line

Tags: gnuplot, curve

I have some values of an experiment I want to plot in the xyz coordinate system. the values are somewhat limited to a certain amount and have thus a beginning and an end. Furthermore I want to plot them and the last point of them should be visible in a special way. Like a unique point with a special color or a special dot. How can I create such a line where the end is visible as a dot or something similar?

Comment: Yes, its possible, but you need to provide some more information. It is possible, but you must distinguish your 'end' point in some way from the others: Is it the last point in the data file? Or is it the one with an e.g. maximum `z`-value? How many points make one line? How is your data file formatted? etc

Comment: Yap, it should be the last point of the plotted line from the measuering data. Its also the maximum value of the x-axis value.

Answer (score 0):

In case that it is the last point, you can use `every` to select it. Unfortunately, there is no 'magic' value to get the last point. You must count the number of entries and use that value:

```
stats 'file.dat' nooutput
last_index = int(STATS_records - 1)
splot 'file.dat' with lines, '' every ::last_index with points
```

Alternatively, you could use the `using` statement, to add some filtering which is true only for this single point which you want to select.

In the most general case, you would have

```
f(i, x, y, z) = ...
splot 'file.dat' with lines, '' using (f($0, $1, $2, $3) ? $1 : 1/0):2:3 with points
```

This skips all points, for which `f` returns `0`. `$0` is the shorthand for `column(0)`, which gives the row index, `$1` gives the numerical value of the first column and so on.

Now it is up to you to define an appropriate filtering function `f`.

If the end point is given e.g. by the point with the maximum `x`-value, you could use:

```
stats 'file.dat' using 1 nooutput
f(x) = (x == STATS_max ? 1 : 0)
splot 'file.dat' with lines, '' using (f($1) ? $1 : 1/0):2:3 with points
```

If you have an other criterium, you must define your function `f` accordingly.

To add a label to this point, you can use the `label` plotting style:

```
splot 'file.dat' with lines, \
      '' using (f($1) ? $1 : 1/0):2:3:(sprintf('(%.1f,%.1f,%.1f)', $1, $2, $3)) \
         offset char 1,1 point notitle
```

Comment: Yap this is also working, but on the other hand I could also simply copy paste that point and print it out somewhat manualy. Still open question how to do it comfortably with like varying numbers and varying maximum values.

The maximal value should be plotted and then somewhat marked

Comment: See my edit. In any case you need to specify in some way, what makes out this 'end point'. And it would be nice, if you would include enough information in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without `stats` which works even with gnuplot 4.4.0 (I guess `stats` was only available in gnuplot 4.6.0).

- use the pseudocolumn 0 (check `help pseudocolumns`), if `$0==0` (i.e. first row) you assign the values to `x0,y0,z0`.
- assign `x1=$1`, `y1=$2`, and `z1=$3`. So after the first plot command the variables `x1,y1,z1` hold the last point's coordinates.
- use the special filename `'+'` (check `special filenames`) for [plotting a single datapoint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452516/7295599).

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### mark startpoint and endpoint of a path
reset

FILE = "SO19426060.dat"

# create some random test data
a = rand(0)
b = rand(0)
c = rand(0)
set table FILE
    splot '+' u (a=a+rand(0)-0.5):(b=b+rand(0)-0.5):(c=c+rand(0)-0.5)
unset table

set grid x
set grid y
set xyplane relative 0

splot FILE u ($0==0?x0=$1:0,x1=$1):($0==0?y0=$2:0,y1=$2):($0==0?z0=$3:0,z1=$3) \
        w l lc rgb "black" notitle, \
       '+' u (x0):(y0):(z0) every ::0::0 w p pt 7 lc rgb "blue" ti "start", \
       '+' u (x1):(y1):(z1) every ::0::0 w p pt 7 lc rgb "red"  ti "end"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]