# Add a single point at an existing plot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the following script to fit a function on a plot. In the output plot I would like to add a single value with etiquette on the fitting curve lets say the point f(3.25). I have read that for gnuplot is very tricky to add one single point on a plot particularly when this plot is a fitting function plot.

Has someone has an idea how to add this single point on the existing plot?

```
set xlabel "1000/T (K^-^1)" font "Helvetica,20"    
#set ylabel "-log(tau_c)"       font "Helvetica,20"    
set ylabel "-log{/Symbol t}_c (ns)"     font "Helvetica,20"    
set title  "$system $type $method"        font "Helvetica,24"    
set xtics      font "Helvetica Bold, 18"                                  
set ytics      font "Helvetica Bold, 18"                                  
#set xrange[0:4]
set border linewidth 3
set xtic auto                          # set xtics automatically
set ytic auto                          # set ytics automatically
#set key on bottom  box lw 3 width 8 height .5 spacing 4 font "Helvetica, 24"
set key  box lw 3 width 4 height .5 spacing 4 font "Helvetica, 24"

set yrange[-5:]
set xrange[1.5:8]
f(x)=A+B*x/(1000-C*x)

A=1 ;B=-227 ; C=245

fit  f(x) "$plot1" u (1000/\$1):(-log10(\$2)) via A,B,C

plot [1.5:8] f(x)  ti "VFT" lw 4,  "$plot1" u (1000/\$1):(-log10(\$2)) ti "$system $type" lw 10



#set key on bottom  box lw 3 width 8 height .5 spacing 4 font "Helvetica, 24"

set terminal postscript eps color dl 2 lw 1 enhanced # font "Helvetica,20"

set output "KWW.eps"                                              



replot
```

Comment: Do you want to add a dot, i.e. a filled circle, or should it use one of the available point styles?

Comment: If it is not a problem could you show both ways?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are several possiblities to set a point/dot:

#### 1. set object

If you have simple points, like a circle, circle wedge or a square, you can use `set object`, which must be define before the respective `plot` command:

```
set object circle at first -5,5 radius char 0.5 \
    fillstyle empty border lc rgb '#aa1100' lw 2
set object circle at graph 0.5,0.9 radius char 1 arc [0:-90] \
    fillcolor rgb 'red' fillstyle solid noborder
set object rectangle at screen 0.6, 0.2 size char 1, char 0.6 \
    fillcolor rgb 'blue' fillstyle solid border lt 2 lw 2

plot x
```

To add a label, you need to use `set label`.

This may be cumbersome, but has the advantage that you can use different line and fill colors, and you can use different coordinate systems (`first`, `graph`, `screen` etc).

The result with 4.6.4 is:

[image]

#### 2. Set an empty label with point option

The `set label` command has a `point` option, which can be used to set a point using the existing point types at a certain coordinate:

```
set label at xPos, yPos, zPos "" point pointtype 7 pointsize 2
```

#### 3. plot with '+'

The last possibility is to use the special filename `+`, which generates a set of coordinates, which are then filtered, and plotted using the `labels` plotting style (or `points` if no label is requested:

```
f(x) = x**2
x1 = 2

set xrange[-5:5]
set style line 1 pointtype 7 linecolor rgb '#22aa22' pointsize 2
plot f(x), \
     '+' using ($0 == 0 ? x1 : NaN):(f(x1)):(sprintf('f(%.1f)', x1)) \
     with labels offset char 1,-0.2 left textcolor rgb 'blue' \
     point linestyle 1 notitle
```

`$0`, or equivalently `column(0)`, is the coordinate index. In the `using` statement only the first one is taken as valid, all other ones are skipped (using `NaN`).

Note, that using `+` requires setting a fixed `xrange`.

This has the advantages (or disadvantages?):

1. You can use the usual `pointtype`.
2. You can only use the axis values as coordinates (like `first` or `second` for the objects above).
3. It may become more difficult to place different point types.
4. It is more involved using different border and fill colors.

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Christoph's excellent answers :

**4. use `stdin` to pipe in the one point**

```
replot "-" using 1:(f($1))
2.0
e
```

and use the method in 3rd answer to label it.

**5. bake a named datablock**
(version > 5.0) that contains the one point, then you can replot without resupplying it every time:

```
$point << EOD
2.0
EOD
replot $point using 1:(f($1)):(sprintf("%.2f",f($1))) with labels
```

Answer (score 1):

**6.** A solution using a **dummy array of length one**:

```
array point[1]

pl [-5:5] x**2, point us (2):(3) pt 7 lc 3
```

[image]

**7.** Or through a **shell command** (see help `piped-data`):

```
pl [-5:5] x**2, "<echo e" us (2):(3) pt 7 lc 3
pl [-5:5] x**2, "<echo 2 3"  pt 7 lc 3
```

**8.** **Special filename '+'**

```
pl [-5:5] x**2, "+" us (2):(3) pt 7 lc 3
```

It seems to be the shortest solution. But note that while it looks like a single point, these are like 500 points (see `show samples`) plotted on the same position.
To have only one point the sampling needs to be temporarily adjusted (see `help plot sampling`)

```
pl [-5:5] x**2, [0:0:1] "+" us (2):(3) pt 7 lc 3
```

**9.** **Function with zero sampling range length**

Shortest to type, but plotting as many points on top of each other as many specified with `samples`

```
pl [-5:5] x**2, [2:2] 3 w p pt 7 lc 3
```

Comment: ad 8. for plotting **only one** point you can do: `plot [-5:5] x**2, '+' u (2):(3) every ::0::0 pt 7 lc 3`. With this you are independent of sampling.