# gnuplot: plotting single point from variable

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to print some single points on a graph. Values for this points come are used previously in the same dictionary. Each of the printed points should be labelled on the legend. So far the closest I got was this

```
plot '-' w p ls 1, '-' w p ls 2, '-' w p ls 3
1 2
e
2 1 
e
3 1.5
e
```

from [here](http://www.gnuplotting.org/plotting-single-points/)

this doesn't work:

```
plot '-' w p ls 1, '-' w p ls 2, '-' w p ls 3
1 var1
e
2 var2
e
3 var4
e
```

Does anybody know if it's possible to do something like this without data files and more complications? 
Also, I tried variations to the above, and searched online, nothing like this was found. Thank you!! :)

I want to compare the values of given variables on a graph.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19457387/2604213

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a `columnhead key`. The example you linked, disables the key (legend) completely. You have to change that. Here is the full example

```
set border linewidth 1.5
set pointsize 1.5
set style line 1 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 5   # square
set style line 2 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 7   # circle
set style line 3 lc rgb '#0060ad' pt 9   # triangle

# unset key
set key on
set key autotitle columnhead

set tics scale 0.75
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set yrange[0:3]
set xrange[0.5:3.5]
set xlabel 'x' 
set ylabel 'y'

# Plot some points 
plot '-'  w p ls 1 , '-' w p ls 2, '-' w p ls 3
"X" "Square"
1 2
e
"X" "Circle"
2 1
e
"X" "Triangle"
3 1.5
e
```

BTW. `plot '-' ...` is actually a `datafile` plot, but with an inline `datafile`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually, my main problem is how to use a variable instead of "2" or "1". (see example in my first post!) Thank you!

Comment: @miro2 Let's talk in this chat room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22573449#22573449

Comment: @miro2: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25543/gnuplot-plotting-single-point-from-variable