# Add a single point to an existing graph in gnuplot using an expression

Tags: gnuplot

A bit stupid question. I want to add a single point to an existing plot in gnuplot. Something like this

```
plot "foo.dat" u 1:2   title 'foo',\
     "<echo '3.0 7.0'" title 'red foo'
```

But I was wondering, is there any way to put an expression instead of giving the coordinates explicitly? Something like

```
plot "foo.dat" u 1:2        title 'foo',\
     "<echo '3.0 log(7.0)'" title 'red foo'
```

I know that I can just add directly the value of `log(7.0)` (`1.9459`) but I was wondering if I could use an expression instead.

As always, thanks for any help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/19452516/2604213

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put in the extra data point via `stdin` (see also `special filenames` in the gp help)

```
plot "foo.dat" title "foo.dat", \
     "-" using 1:(log($2)) title "extra point"
3.0 7.0
e
```

and use `using` on it, or, in (gp v>5.0), use the new inline data facility and do the same (check `help inline data`)

```
$extra << EOD
3.0 7.0
EOD
plot "foo.dat", $extra using 1:(log($2))
```

It would of course also work with your shell command + a using statement.

Comment: Thanks @Karl. Would this work for several data points? I mean, can I add a `3  log(7)` and a `5   log(8)`. Probably the second way will work.

Comment: of course. Just add whatever additional data you want before the "e", or "EOD". Check `special-filenames` and `inline data` in the gp documentation.