# drawing multiple lines using a script in gnuplot

Tags: windows, graph, gnuplot

I have made a script to draw some lines using gnuplot. My script is given below:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot
reset
set terminal wxt
set yrange [0:100]
set xrange [0:100]
unset colorbox
set style arrow 1 nohead lc rgb 'black'
set style arrow 2 nohead lc rgb 'red'
set arrow 1 from 1,10 to 2,10 nohead
plot [0:15][0:22]-0.2*x+7.8
set arrow 1 from 2,15 to 3,15 nohead
plot [0:15][0:22]-0.2*x+12.8
set arrow 1 from 3,20 to 4,20 nohead
plot [0:15][0:22]-0.2*x+17.8
```

I want to draw all the three lines but when I run it, I am getting only one line as output. Is there anything wrong in the script?

Answer (score 1):

You need to issue only a single `plot` command:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gnuplot
reset
set terminal wxt
set yrange [0:100]
set xrange [0:100]

set style arrow 1 nohead lc rgb 'black'
set style arrow 2 nohead lc rgb 'red'
set arrow 1 from 1,10 to 2,10 nohead
set arrow 2 from 2,15 to 3,15 nohead
set arrow 3 from 3,20 to 4,20 nohead
plot [0:15][0:22] -0.2*x+7.8, \
    -0.2*x+12.8, \
    -0.2*x+17.8
```

Comment: is it possible to draw these four points (1, 5),(2,10),(3, 15),(4, 20) in the above script before drawing the lines? how will I do this? @kebs

Comment: This is actually a separate question, you might want to look [over here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452516/). But your original question as been answered, so you can accept one of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Different arrows must have different indices. So use `set arrow 1 ...`, `set arrow 2 ...`, and `set arrow 3 ...`        instead of three times specifying `set arrow 1 ...`.

A few other points in your script:

- Styles defined by `set style arrow` are assigned to an arrow with the `arrowstyle` keyword.

So one can use this:

```
set style arrow 1 nohead lc rgb 'black'
set style arrow 2 nohead lc rgb 'red'
set style arrow 3 nohead lc rgb 'green'

set arrow 1 from 1,10 to 2,10 arrowstyle 1
set arrow 2 from 2,15 to 3,15 arrowstyle 2
set arrow 3 from 3,20 to 4,20 arrowstyle 3

plot [0:15][0:22]-0.2*x+7.8  ,\
                 -0.2*x+12.8 ,\
                 -0.2*x+17.8
```

or this:

```
set arrow 1 from 1,10 to 2,10 nohead lc rgb 'black'
set arrow 2 from 2,15 to 3,15 nohead lc rgb 'red'
set arrow 3 from 3,20 to 4,20 nohead lc rgb 'green'

plot [0:15][0:22]-0.2*x+7.8  ,\
                 -0.2*x+12.8 ,\
                 -0.2*x+17.8
```

- The command `set xrange [0:100]` is overwritten by `[0:15]` in your `plot` command. The same for `yrange`.
- One plot command is enough.
- `colorbox` is only needed on pm3d plots