# Capture hypertext value in gnuplot 5

Tags: gnuplot, bind, label

I do love the new hypertext feature in gnuplot 5; but I am still missing something: I would like not just to hover near a point to read some hidden text, but I also would like to be able to capture the hypertext.

If this hypertext were a mouse variable (just like MOUSE_X and MOUSE_Y), capturing  it would be an easy task; however this seems not to be the case.

Has anybody a workaround to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

In this respect it might be interesting, that in the newest version (`-rc1`) a single left-click shall copy the hypertext into clipboard, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61924355/11769765.

For older versions like gnuplot 5.2, the following code is a (not very efficient) work-around to
grab the closest data point:

```
set print $Data
do for [x=-5:5] {
    print x, x**2
}
unset print

set table $Text
    plot $Data us (sprintf("x=%g, y=%g",$1,$2)) w table
unset table

array snappoint[1]

set macro
myplot = 'plot $Data u 1:2:($Text[$0+1]) w labels hypertext point pt 7 lc 1 title "f(x)"'

bind Button1 'mx=MOUSE_X; my=MOUSE_Y; i=1;\
    set table $distance; \
        plot $Data u (d=sqrt(($1-mx)**2+($2-my)**2), di=$0==0?(xi=$1,yi=$2,d):\
                     (d<di?(i=int($0+1),xi=$1,yi=$2,d):di), d) w table;\
    unset table;\
    print i," ", $Text[i];\
    @myplot, snappoint us (xi):(yi) pt 6 ps 2 lc 3 t $Text[i]'

@myplot
```

A left click marks the closest point and prints e.g. `3  x=-3, y=9` to the console.

[image]

For simplicity, the distance is computed here only with axis coordinates, while screen coordinates would be better. The transformation could be done with variables `GPVAL_X_MIN`, etc.

Comment: interesting! What is the idea behind `"<echo 1"`? Plotting a single datapoint or something else?

Comment: `"<echo 1"` is used to plot a single point, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61059693/11769765. The `1` is just a dummy, because an empty line alone does not count as a row. One could also use `"<echo foo"`.

Comment: with `<echo` I get a flashing console window. To avoid this, an alternative suggestion for plotting a single data point would be to define earlier `array A[1]` (even without any defined value) and then later use `plot A u (xi):(yi)`. Actually, you suggested this in the link above.