# gnuplot qt: hyperlinks and click events

Tags: gnuplot

Some terminal supports `hypertext`. When hover a data point, some text is shown, e.g.

```
$data <<EOD
1.2 0.12 Berlin
2 0.83 Paris
3 0.6 London
4.3 0.5 Rom
EOD

plot $data w labels hypertext
```

Is there a possibility to have interaction, i.e.  bind a click event to print the text on console or execute a hyperlink?
It's likely possible with `svg`, but with `qt` console?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41063899/capture-hypertext-value-in-gnuplot-5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current qt implementation sends the hypertext string to the clipboard on mouse click.  How to retrieve it from the clipboard depends on your desktop configuration. The classic X11 behavior was that middle-mouse-click would paste from the clipboard to the active window, but these days that expectation is often in vain.

In case it helps you to pin down the behavior on your system, the Qt command issued is this:

```
QApplication::clipboard()->setText(m_selectedHypertext);
```

The wxt terminal does essentially the same thing, with the added wrinkle that wxWidgets can have multiple back-ends that may interpret "clipboard" in different ways. There the command executed is

```
wxt_set_clipboard(wxt_display_hypertext);
```

As you suggest, the svg implementation uses javascript. You could modify the file `gnuplot_svg.js` to customize it however you like.

Comment: I have openSUSE Leap 15.0. I tried wxt,qt and x11. For all, double right click returns the mouse coordinates into clipboard, available then with Ctrl+Shift+V. But hypertext is never copied.

Comment: The text is selected by single left-click, not double right-click.

Comment: Sorry, I meant double left-click copies the mouse coordinates into clipboard. (Right-click starts zooming). Nothing happens for single left-click.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was testing with the -rc1 version of the new gnuplot release. It works there. I hadn't realized that behavior was added so recently.  So the answer is "yes it would be possible and it is in the new release".