# How to calculate a curve length in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file containing the following data:

```
x    z
0.1  0
0.12 0.1
0.12 0.14
0.13 0.15
0.15 0.15
...   ...
```

I would like to calculate the curve length

```
sum_{n=0->end of file}(sqrt((x_n+1-x_n)^2+(z_n+1-z_n)^2))
```

I guess I have to use a recursive function.But don't know how to use it with a data file.  How could I do that in gnuplot script?

Comment: Problem solved? If yes, then please accept the answer indicating that the question is answered. If no, please clarify. Any response would be polite and appreciated.

Comment: Problem solved? Question answered?

Answer (score 2):

You certainly could define a recursive function, but it is not necessary.
You simply sum up all the path lengths between two consecutive points.
For the first line, i.e. if the pseudocolumn 0 (basically, line index zero-based, check `help pseudocolumns`) is equal to `0`, initialize your variables `x1` and `y1` and `L`. For each line assign `x0=x1` and `x1=$1`. With this, `x0` holds the previous x-value and `x1` the current x-value. Same for `y0=y1` and `y1=$2`. Calculate the length `dL` of that piece and sum all pieces up in `L`.

Note that `dL(n)` is actually not a function of `n`, but with this function call you assure that the values of `x0,x1,y0,y1` at the time of calling are taken. Alternatively, you could pass them as function parameters `L(x0,x1,y0,y1)` which, however, would be a bit lengthy.

Furthermore, the construct `'+' u (x1):(y1) ... every ::0::0` is one way of many ways to [plot a single data point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452516/7295599).

**Script:**

```
### determine path length
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 0.1   0
 0.12  0.1
 0.12  0.14
 0.13  0.15
 0.15  0.15
 0.17  0.10
 0.14  0.04
 0.13  0.08
 0.13  0.11
 0.15  0.12
 0.16  0.10
 0.14  0.07
EOD

dL(n) = sqrt((x1-x0)**2 + (y1-y0)**2)
set key noautotitle

plot $Data u ($0==0?(L=0,x1=$1,y1=$2):0,x0=x1,x1=$1):\
             (y0=y1,y1=$2,L=L+dL(0),y1) w l lc "red", \
       '+' u (x1):(y1):(sprintf("L=%.3g",L)) every ::0::0 w labels offset 0,-0.5
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]