# Extract Value from Spline Fit in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I know it is possible to draw a spline through data points in gnuplot using the command

```
plot 'data' u 1:2 smooth acsplines
```

but is it possible to evaluate the spline at an aribtrary point? ie. I'm looking for a functionality like

```
spline(1.54)
```

I could not find any information about this in the gnuplot documentation.

Comment: What exactly do you want as return value? The slope of the tangent at that given point or just the y-value?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - I would like the y-value at an arbitrary x-value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first thought would be the following:

- plot the `acsplines` into a table (check `help table`)
- set `samples` large enough to have good precision (check `help samples`)
- use `stats` to find the minimum distance from your desired value `x0` (check `help stats` and `show var STATS`)
- plot the data points, acplines and [add a single point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452516/7295599)

**Script:**

```
### find a point on acsplines curve
reset session

$Data <<EOD
# x   y    weight
  0   4.0   10
  1   5.0  100
  2   3.0   10
  3   3.5    1
  4   2.0    1
  5   4.0    1
EOD

set table $acsplines
    set samples 1000
    plot $Data u 1:2:3 smooth acsplines
unset table

x0 = 1.54     # desired x-value
stats $acsplines u 2:(abs($1-x0)) nooutput
y0 = STATS_pos_min_y
print myTitle=sprintf("x=%g, y=%.3f",x0,y0)

plot $Data      u 1:2 w p pt 7 lc "red"  ti "points", \
     $acsplines u 1:2 w l      lc "blue" ti "acsplines", \
            '+' u (x0):(y0) every ::::0 w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "web-green" ti myTitle
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
x=1.54, y=4.285
```

[image]