# Gnuplot columnheader doesn't work with image (colormaps)

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a data file, with 4 columns:

```
x y Temperature Time :
0.025525    0.0003  4.20188 16.65
0.025525    0.0009  4.20189 16.65
0.025525    0.0015  4.20189 16.65
0.025525    0.0021  4.2019  16.65
0.025525    0.0027  4.2019  16.65
0.025525    0.0033  4.2019  16.65
0.025525    0.0039  4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.0045  4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.0051  4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.0057  4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.0003  4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.0009  4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.0068  4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.0074  4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.008   4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.0086  4.20191 16.65
0.025525    0.0092  4.2019  16.65
0.025525    0.0098  4.2019  16.65
0.025525    0.0104  4.2019  16.65
0.025525    0.011   4.20189 16.65
0.025525    0.0116  4.20189 16.65
0.025525    0.0122  4.20188 16.65
0.026575    0.0003  4.20196 16.65
0.026575    0.0009  4.20196 16.65
0.026575    0.0015  4.20197 16.65
0.026575    0.0021  4.20197 16.65
0.026575    0.0027  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0033  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0039  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0045  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0051  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0057  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0003  4.20199 16.65
0.026575    0.0009  4.20199 16.65
0.026575    0.0068  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0074  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.008   4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0086  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0092  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0098  4.20198 16.65
0.026575    0.0104  4.20197 16.65
0.026575    0.011   4.20197 16.65
0.026575    0.0116  4.20196 16.65
0.026575    0.0122  4.20196 16.65
0.027625    0.0003  4.20207 16.65
0.027625    0.0009  4.20208 16.65
0.027625    0.0015  4.20208 16.65
0.027625    0.0021  4.20209 16.65
0.027625    0.0027  4.20209 16.65
0.027625    0.0033  4.20209 16.65
0.027625    0.0039  4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.0045  4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.0051  4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.0057  4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.0003  4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.0009  4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.0068  4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.0074  4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.008   4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.0086  4.2021  16.65
0.027625    0.0092  4.20209 16.65
0.027625    0.0098  4.20209 16.65
0.027625    0.0104  4.20209 16.65
0.027625    0.011   4.20208 16.65
0.027625    0.0116  4.20208 16.65
0.027625    0.0122  4.20207 16.65
0.028675    0.0003  4.20222 16.65
0.028675    0.0009  4.20222 16.65
0.028675    0.0015  4.20223 16.65
0.028675    0.0021  4.20223 16.65
0.028675    0.0027  4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.0033  4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.0039  4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.0045  4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.0051  4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.0057  4.20225 16.65
0.028675    0.0003  4.20225 16.65
0.028675    0.0009  4.20225 16.65
0.028675    0.0068  4.20225 16.65
0.028675    0.0074  4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.008   4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.0086  4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.0092  4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.0098  4.20224 16.65
0.028675    0.0104  4.20223 16.65
0.028675    0.011   4.20223 16.65
0.028675    0.0116  4.20222 16.65
0.028675    0.0122  4.20222 16.65
0.029725    0.0003  4.20238 16.65
0.029725    0.0009  4.20239 16.65
0.029725    0.0015  4.20239 16.65
0.029725    0.0021  4.2024  16.65
0.029725    0.0027  4.2024  16.65
0.029725    0.0033  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0039  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0045  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0051  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0057  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0003  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0009  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0068  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0074  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.008   4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0086  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0092  4.20241 16.65
0.029725    0.0098  4.2024  16.65
0.029725    0.0104  4.2024  16.65
0.029725    0.011   4.20239 16.65
0.029725    0.0116  4.20239 16.65
0.029725    0.0122  4.20238 16.65
0.030775    0.0003  4.20256 16.65
0.030775    0.0009  4.20257 16.65
0.030775    0.0015  4.20257 16.65
0.030775    0.0021  4.20258 16.65
0.030775    0.0027  4.20258 16.65
0.030775    0.0033  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0039  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0045  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0051  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0057  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0003  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0009  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0068  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0074  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.008   4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0086  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0092  4.20259 16.65
0.030775    0.0098  4.20258 16.65
0.030775    0.0104  4.20258 16.65
0.030775    0.011   4.20257 16.65
0.030775    0.0116  4.20257 16.65
0.030775    0.0122  4.20256 16.65
0.031825    0.0003  4.20275 16.65
0.031825    0.0009  4.20275 16.65
0.031825    0.0015  4.20276 16.65
0.031825    0.0021  4.20277 16.65
0.031825    0.0027  4.20277 16.65
0.031825    0.0033  4.20277 16.65
0.031825    0.0039  4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.0045  4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.0051  4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.0057  4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.0003  4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.0009  4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.0068  4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.0074  4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.008   4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.0086  4.20278 16.65
0.031825    0.0092  4.20277 16.65
0.031825    0.0098  4.20277 16.65
0.031825    0.0104  4.20277 16.65
0.031825    0.011   4.20276 16.65
0.031825    0.0116  4.20275 16.65
0.031825    0.0122  4.20275 16.65
0.032875    0.0003  4.20294 16.65
0.032875    0.0009  4.20294 16.65
0.032875    0.0015  4.20295 16.65
0.032875    0.0021  4.20296 16.65
0.032875    0.0027  4.20296 16.65
0.032875    0.0033  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0039  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0045  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0051  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0057  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0003  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0009  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0068  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0074  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.008   4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0086  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0092  4.20297 16.65
0.032875    0.0098  4.20296 16.65
0.032875    0.0104  4.20296 16.65
0.032875    0.011   4.20295 16.65
0.032875    0.0116  4.20294 16.65
0.032875    0.0122  4.20294 16.65
0.033925    0.0003  4.20312 16.65
0.033925    0.0009  4.20313 16.65
0.033925    0.0015  4.20314 16.65
0.033925    0.0021  4.20314 16.65
0.033925    0.0027  4.20315 16.65
0.033925    0.0033  4.20315 16.65
0.033925    0.0039  4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.0045  4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.0051  4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.0057  4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.0003  4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.0009  4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.0068  4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.0074  4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.008   4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.0086  4.20316 16.65
0.033925    0.0092  4.20315 16.65
0.033925    0.0098  4.20315 16.65
0.033925    0.0104  4.20314 16.65
0.033925    0.011   4.20314 16.65
0.033925    0.0116  4.20313 16.65
0.033925    0.0122  4.20312 16.65
0.034975    0.0003  4.2033  16.65
0.034975    0.0009  4.20331 16.65
0.034975    0.0015  4.20332 16.65
0.034975    0.0021  4.20333 16.65
0.034975    0.0027  4.20333 16.65
0.034975    0.0033  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0039  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0045  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0051  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0057  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0003  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0009  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0068  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0074  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.008   4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0086  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0092  4.20334 16.65
0.034975    0.0098  4.20333 16.65
0.034975    0.0104  4.20333 16.65
0.034975    0.011   4.20332 16.65
0.034975    0.0116  4.20331 16.65
0.034975    0.0122  4.2033  16.65
0.036025    0.0003  4.20347 16.65
0.036025    0.0009  4.20348 16.65
0.036025    0.0015  4.20349 16.65
0.036025    0.0021  4.2035  16.65
0.036025    0.0027  4.2035  16.65
0.036025    0.0033  4.20351 16.65
0.036025    0.0039  4.20351 16.65
0.036025    0.0045  4.20351 16.65
0.036025    0.0051  4.20352 16.65
0.036025    0.0057  4.20352 16.65
0.036025    0.0003  4.20352 16.65
0.036025    0.0009  4.20352 16.65
0.036025    0.0068  4.20352 16.65
0.036025    0.0074  4.20352 16.65
0.036025    0.008   4.20351 16.65
0.036025    0.0086  4.20351 16.65
0.036025    0.0092  4.20351 16.65
0.036025    0.0098  4.2035  16.65
0.036025    0.0104  4.2035  16.65
0.036025    0.011   4.20349 16.65
0.036025    0.0116  4.20348 16.65
0.036025    0.0122  4.20347 16.65
0.037075    0.0003  4.20363 16.65
0.037075    0.0009  4.20364 16.65
0.037075    0.0015  4.20365 16.65
0.037075    0.0021  4.20365 16.65
0.037075    0.0027  4.20366 16.65
0.037075    0.0033  4.20366 16.65
0.037075    0.0039  4.20367 16.65
0.037075    0.0045  4.20367 16.65
0.037075    0.0051  4.20367 16.65
0.037075    0.0057  4.20368 16.65
0.037075    0.0003  4.20367 16.65
0.037075    0.0009  4.20367 16.65
0.037075    0.0068  4.20368 16.65
0.037075    0.0074  4.20367 16.65
0.037075    0.008   4.20367 16.65
0.037075    0.0086  4.20367 16.65
0.037075    0.0092  4.20366 16.65
0.037075    0.0098  4.20366 16.65
0.037075    0.0104  4.20365 16.65
0.037075    0.011   4.20365 16.65
0.037075    0.0116  4.20364 16.65
0.037075    0.0122  4.20363 16.65
0.038125    0.0003  4.20377 16.65
0.038125    0.0009  4.20378 16.65
0.038125    0.0015  4.20378 16.65
0.038125    0.0021  4.20379 16.65
0.038125    0.0027  4.2038  16.65
0.038125    0.0033  4.2038  16.65
0.038125    0.0039  4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.0045  4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.0051  4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.0057  4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.0003  4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.0009  4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.0068  4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.0074  4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.008   4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.0086  4.20381 16.65
0.038125    0.0092  4.2038  16.65
0.038125    0.0098  4.2038  16.65
0.038125    0.0104  4.20379 16.65
0.038125    0.011   4.20378 16.65
0.038125    0.0116  4.20378 16.65
0.038125    0.0122  4.20377 16.65
0.039175    0.0003  4.20388 16.65
0.039175    0.0009  4.20389 16.65
0.039175    0.0015  4.2039  16.65
0.039175    0.0021  4.20391 16.65
0.039175    0.0027  4.20391 16.65
0.039175    0.0033  4.20392 16.65
0.039175    0.0039  4.20392 16.65
0.039175    0.0045  4.20392 16.65
0.039175    0.0051  4.20393 16.65
0.039175    0.0057  4.20393 16.65
0.039175    0.0003  4.20393 16.65
0.039175    0.0009  4.20393 16.65
0.039175    0.0068  4.20393 16.65
0.039175    0.0074  4.20393 16.65
0.039175    0.008   4.20392 16.65
0.039175    0.0086  4.20392 16.65
0.039175    0.0092  4.20392 16.65
0.039175    0.0098  4.20391 16.65
0.039175    0.0104  4.20391 16.65
0.039175    0.011   4.2039  16.65
0.039175    0.0116  4.20389 16.65
0.039175    0.0122  4.20388 16.65
0.040225    0.0003  4.20396 16.65
0.040225    0.0009  4.20397 16.65
0.040225    0.0015  4.20398 16.65
0.040225    0.0021  4.20399 16.65
0.040225    0.0027  4.20399 16.65
0.040225    0.0033  4.204   16.65
0.040225    0.0039  4.204   16.65
0.040225    0.0045  4.20401 16.65
0.040225    0.0051  4.20401 16.65
0.040225    0.0057  4.20401 16.65
0.040225    0.0003  4.20401 16.65
0.040225    0.0009  4.20401 16.65
0.040225    0.0068  4.20401 16.65
0.040225    0.0074  4.20401 16.65
0.040225    0.008   4.20401 16.65
0.040225    0.0086  4.204   16.65
0.040225    0.0092  4.204   16.65
0.040225    0.0098  4.20399 16.65
0.040225    0.0104  4.20399 16.65
0.040225    0.011   4.20398 16.65
0.040225    0.0116  4.20397 16.65
0.040225    0.0122  4.20396 16.65
0.041275    0.0003  4.20401 16.65
0.041275    0.0009  4.20402 16.65
0.041275    0.0015  4.20403 16.65
0.041275    0.0021  4.20404 16.65
0.041275    0.0027  4.20405 16.65
0.041275    0.0033  4.20405 16.65
0.041275    0.0039  4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.0045  4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.0051  4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.0057  4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.0003  4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.0009  4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.0068  4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.0074  4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.008   4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.0086  4.20406 16.65
0.041275    0.0092  4.20405 16.65
0.041275    0.0098  4.20405 16.65
0.041275    0.0104  4.20404 16.65
0.041275    0.011   4.20403 16.65
0.041275    0.0116  4.20402 16.65
0.041275    0.0122  4.20401 16.65
0.042325    0.0003  4.20402 16.65
0.042325    0.0009  4.20403 16.65
0.042325    0.0015  4.20404 16.65
0.042325    0.0021  4.20405 16.65
0.042325    0.0027  4.20406 16.65
0.042325    0.0033  4.20406 16.65
0.042325    0.0039  4.20407 16.65
0.042325    0.0045  4.20407 16.65
0.042325    0.0051  4.20407 16.65
0.042325    0.0057  4.20408 16.65
0.042325    0.0003  4.20407 16.65
0.042325    0.0009  4.20407 16.65
0.042325    0.0068  4.20408 16.65
0.042325    0.0074  4.20407 16.65
0.042325    0.008   4.20407 16.65
0.042325    0.0086  4.20407 16.65
0.042325    0.0092  4.20406 16.65
0.042325    0.0098  4.20406 16.65
0.042325    0.0104  4.20405 16.65
0.042325    0.011   4.20404 16.65
0.042325    0.0116  4.20403 16.65
0.042325    0.0122  4.20402 16.65
0.043375    0.0003  4.20399 16.65
0.043375    0.0009  4.204   16.65
0.043375    0.0015  4.20401 16.65
0.043375    0.0021  4.20402 16.65
0.043375    0.0027  4.20403 16.65
0.043375    0.0033  4.20403 16.65
0.043375    0.0039  4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.0045  4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.0051  4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.0057  4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.0003  4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.0009  4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.0068  4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.0074  4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.008   4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.0086  4.20404 16.65
0.043375    0.0092  4.20403 16.65
0.043375    0.0098  4.20403 16.65
0.043375    0.0104  4.20402 16.65
0.043375    0.011   4.20401 16.65
0.043375    0.0116  4.204   16.65
0.043375    0.0122  4.20399 16.65
0.044425    0.0003  4.20391 16.65
0.044425    0.0009  4.20392 16.65
0.044425    0.0015  4.20393 16.65
0.044425    0.0021  4.20394 16.65
0.044425    0.0027  4.20394 16.65
0.044425    0.0033  4.20395 16.65
0.044425    0.0039  4.20395 16.65
0.044425    0.0045  4.20396 16.65
0.044425    0.0051  4.20396 16.65
0.044425    0.0057  4.20396 16.65
0.044425    0.0003  4.20396 16.65
0.044425    0.0009  4.20396 16.65
0.044425    0.0068  4.20396 16.65
0.044425    0.0074  4.20396 16.65
0.044425    0.008   4.20396 16.65
0.044425    0.0086  4.20395 16.65
0.044425    0.0092  4.20395 16.65
0.044425    0.0098  4.20394 16.65
0.044425    0.0104  4.20394 16.65
0.044425    0.011   4.20393 16.65
0.044425    0.0116  4.20392 16.65
0.044425    0.0122  4.20391 16.65
0.045475    0.0003  4.20377 16.65
0.045475    0.0009  4.20378 16.65
0.045475    0.0015  4.20379 16.65
0.045475    0.0021  4.2038  16.65
0.045475    0.0027  4.2038  16.65
0.045475    0.0033  4.20381 16.65
0.045475    0.0039  4.20381 16.65
0.045475    0.0045  4.20382 16.65
0.045475    0.0051  4.20382 16.65
0.045475    0.0057  4.20382 16.65
0.045475    0.0003  4.20382 16.65
0.045475    0.0009  4.20382 16.65
0.045475    0.0068  4.20382 16.65
0.045475    0.0074  4.20382 16.65
0.045475    0.008   4.20382 16.65
0.045475    0.0086  4.20381 16.65
0.045475    0.0092  4.20381 16.65
0.045475    0.0098  4.2038  16.65
0.045475    0.0104  4.2038  16.65
0.045475    0.011   4.20379 16.65
0.045475    0.0116  4.20378 16.65
0.045475    0.0122  4.20377 16.65
0.046525    0.0003  4.20356 16.65
0.046525    0.0009  4.20357 16.65
0.046525    0.0015  4.20358 16.65
0.046525    0.0021  4.20359 16.65
0.046525    0.0027  4.20359 16.65
0.046525    0.0033  4.2036  16.65
0.046525    0.0039  4.2036  16.65
0.046525    0.0045  4.20361 16.65
0.046525    0.0051  4.20361 16.65
0.046525    0.0057  4.20361 16.65
0.046525    0.0003  4.2036  16.65
0.046525    0.0009  4.2036  16.65
0.046525    0.0068  4.20361 16.65
0.046525    0.0074  4.20361 16.65
0.046525    0.008   4.20361 16.65
0.046525    0.0086  4.2036  16.65
0.046525    0.0092  4.2036  16.65
0.046525    0.0098  4.20359 16.65
0.046525    0.0104  4.20359 16.65
0.046525    0.011   4.20358 16.65
0.046525    0.0116  4.20357 16.65
0.046525    0.0122  4.20356 16.65
0.047575    0.0003  4.20328 16.65
0.047575    0.0009  4.20329 16.65
0.047575    0.0015  4.2033  16.65
0.047575    0.0021  4.2033  16.65
0.047575    0.0027  4.20331 16.65
0.047575    0.0033  4.20331 16.65
0.047575    0.0039  4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.0045  4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.0051  4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.0057  4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.0003  4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.0009  4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.0068  4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.0074  4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.008   4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.0086  4.20332 16.65
0.047575    0.0092  4.20331 16.65
0.047575    0.0098  4.20331 16.65
0.047575    0.0104  4.2033  16.65
0.047575    0.011   4.2033  16.65
0.047575    0.0116  4.20329 16.65
0.047575    0.0122  4.20328 16.65
0.048625    0.0003  4.20291 16.65
0.048625    0.0009  4.20292 16.65
0.048625    0.0015  4.20293 16.65
0.048625    0.0021  4.20293 16.65
0.048625    0.0027  4.20294 16.65
0.048625    0.0033  4.20294 16.65
0.048625    0.0039  4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.0045  4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.0051  4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.0057  4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.0003  4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.0009  4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.0068  4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.0074  4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.008   4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.0086  4.20295 16.65
0.048625    0.0092  4.20294 16.65
0.048625    0.0098  4.20294 16.65
0.048625    0.0104  4.20293 16.65
0.048625    0.011   4.20293 16.65
0.048625    0.0116  4.20292 16.65
0.048625    0.0122  4.20291 16.65
0.049675    0.0003  4.20245 16.65
0.049675    0.0009  4.20246 16.65
0.049675    0.0015  4.20247 16.65
0.049675    0.0021  4.20247 16.65
0.049675    0.0027  4.20247 16.65
0.049675    0.0033  4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.0039  4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.0045  4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.0051  4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.0057  4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.0003  4.20247 16.65
0.049675    0.0009  4.20247 16.65
0.049675    0.0068  4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.0074  4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.008   4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.0086  4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.0092  4.20248 16.65
0.049675    0.0098  4.20247 16.65
0.049675    0.0104  4.20247 16.65
0.049675    0.011   4.20247 16.65
0.049675    0.0116  4.20246 16.65
0.049675    0.0122  4.20245 16.65
0.050725    0.0003  4.20189 16.65
0.050725    0.0009  4.20189 16.65
0.050725    0.0015  4.20189 16.65
0.050725    0.0021  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0027  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0033  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0039  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0045  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0051  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0057  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0003  4.20181 16.65
0.050725    0.0009  4.20181 16.65
0.050725    0.0068  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0074  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.008   4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0086  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0092  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0098  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.0104  4.2019  16.65
0.050725    0.011   4.20189 16.65
0.050725    0.0116  4.20189 16.65
0.050725    0.0122  4.20189 16.65
```

I plot this from a file, with multiple indexes. Above is 1st index for example. For all indexes then it saves in pdf file as different images. I use the line below to plot it:

```
plot filein index 0  using ( $1 ):( $2 ):($3) notitle  with image
```

It works, and no title is there as expected.

[image]

I want to put title on each image, which is the time in 4th column (different for each index). So I use columnhead command for taking 1st point in 4th column for each image:

`plot filein index 3  using ( $1 ):( $2 ):($3)   with image  title columnhead(4)`

Then it doesn't show the plot properly (gives weird overlapped image), and also gives a warning: Image data corruption. Title is correct though.
[image]

I tried it using set style data points, and columnhead works for that. But I need colormaps with nice titles, and columnhead.

Does columnhead don't work with colormaps? Or somehow it is not letting the gnuplot take other data? Please let me know if you see some issue in my code, or if there are other ways to do this. I don't mind if the value in 4th column is not in title, it can be in label or key or anywhere on the plot.

Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have two problems:

1. The default position of the key (or legend) is **inside** the graph area in the top right corner. But in your case I guess it is buried below the image. I am not aware that you can bring the key to front (maybe with newer gnuplot versions). Well, you could place the key/legend outside the graph, but then you need to get the value first.
2. for the plotting style `with image` you need a strict matrix, i.e. regular x,y values. The option `title columnhead(4)` will "sacrifice" the first line from your matrix and hence will "mess up" your `with image` graph.

Two suggestions which come to my mind (maybe there are better ones):

1. use a keyentry (check `help keyentry`) to put the key/legend on top of the `with image` graph. Before, store the value of the 4th column into the variabe `myTime`.
2. plot your value `with labels` to a suitable position. `plot '+' u (3.5):(4.5):(sprintf("%g",myTime)) every ::::0 w labels` is one possible way to [plot a single datapoint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452516/7295599) (or label) at a specific location.

**Script:**

```
### key/legend in combination "with image"
reset session

$Data  <<EOD
 1   1    1   9.99
 1   2    2   9.99
 1   3    3   9.99
 1   4    4   9.99
 2   1    5   9.99
 2   2    6   9.99
 2   3    7   9.99
 2   4    8   9.99
 3   1    9   9.99
 3   2   10   9.99
 3   3   11   9.99
 3   4   12   9.99
EOD

set size ratio -1
set tics out
set key noautotitle

set multiplot layout 1,2

    set key at graph 0.98, graph 1.0 reverse right
    plot $Data u 1:2:(myTime=$4,$3) index 0 w image, \
        keyentry ti sprintf("%g",myTime)

    plot $Data u 1:2:(myTime=$4,$3) index 0 w image, \
         '+' u (3.5):(4.5):(sprintf("%g",myTime)) every ::::0 w labels right offset -0.5,-0.5

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

In order to get the title from the data you have to go through the data at least once. You could do this using `stats` (check `help stats`), actually without being interesting in statistics but just to extract the value in the first data line (check `help every`).

**Script:**

```
### key/legend in combination "with image"
reset session

$Data  <<EOD
 1   1    1   9.99
 1   2    2   9.99
 1   3    3   9.99
 1   4    4   9.99
 2   1    5   9.99
 2   2    6   9.99
 2   3    7   9.99
 2   4    8   9.99
 3   1    9   9.99
 3   2   10   9.99
 3   3   11   9.99
 3   4   12   9.99
EOD

set size ratio -1
set tics out
set key noautotitle

stats $Data u (myValue=$4) every :::0 nooutput
set title sprintf("Value in column 4 is: %g", myValue)

plot $Data u 1:2:3 index 0 w image,
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This works!! Thank you :) Is it also possible to save the myTime variable before the plot line somehow? That way I can use it in title as well instead of key.

Comment: @AnangDadhich you have to define the graph title before your actual plot. So, in order to extract the value of the 4th column into the variable `myTime` you have to go through the data either during a preceding `plot` or `stats` command. If your data is already in a datablock, then you could do it directly: `set title word($Data[1],4)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me whether the line `x y temperature time` is present in your data file or not; and if it is present, whether it is repeated for each data block or not.

With that line present, your sample data plots successfully using the command `plot DATA index 0  using ( $1 ):( $2 ):($3) with image title columnhead(4)` yielding `time` as the plot title.  But that's not what you want.

Assuming instead that the extra header line `x y ...` is ***NOT*** present in your data file, the command

```
plot DATA index 0 using ($1):($2):(Title=strcol(4),$3) with image title Title
```

does what you ask, and should work for any data block in the file.

Finally, if that extra header line is present as the first line of the file but not in any of the subsequent data block the same command works with the addition of `skip 1` so that the first line of the file is ignored.

```
set key opaque box
plot DATA skip 1 index 0  using ( $1 ):( $2 ):(T=strcol(4),$3)   with image title T
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
The header line is not in the data file, sorry for that.
When I use your method, it gives an error:
                                   
: expecting "title" for plot.

Somehow it is not reading the variable Title. Do I need to define it somewhere first?

Comment: @AnangDadhich if you get that error message, I suspect that you are running a gnuplot version <5.4.0. For this script to work I guess you need gnuplot>=5.4.0