# GNUPLOT error No Previous filename in last line of a Lagrangian Double Pendulum GIF generator

Tags: math, gnuplot, physics, ode

Good night. I am more than 5 hours trying to make a simple GIF of a LaGrangian Double Pendulum. The math is ok, everything is fine, but I can't generate the gif because everytime I try to load I have this same error, and nowhere on the internet I can find a solution. Here is my code below:

```
# Constants
m1 = 1.0
m2 = 1.0
L1 = 1.0
L2 = 1.0
g = 9.8

# Initial conditions
theta1_0 = 0.0
theta2_0 = 0.0
theta1_dot_0 = 0.0
theta2_dot_0 = 0.0

# Time
dt = 0.01
t_max = 10.0

# Initial values of theta1, theta2, theta1_dot, and theta2_dot
theta1 = theta1_0
theta2 = theta2_0
theta1_dot = theta1_dot_0
theta2_dot = theta2_dot_0

# Set output file
set term gif animate delay 10 optimize optimize
set output "double_pendulum.gif"

# Numerical integration using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method
do for [i = 1:int(t_max / dt)] {
    # Calculate derivatives
    dtheta1_dt = theta1_dot
    dtheta2_dt = theta2_dot
    dtheta1_dot_dt = (m2 * g * sin(theta2) * cos(theta1 - theta2) - m2 * sin(theta1 - theta2) * (L1 * theta1_dot**2 * cos(theta1 - theta2) + L2 * theta2_dot**2) - (m1 + m2) * g * sin(theta1)) / (L1 * (m1 + m2 * sin(theta1 - theta2)**2))
    dtheta2_dot_dt = (( (m1 + m2) * (L1 * theta1_dot**2 * sin(theta1 - theta2) - g * sin(theta2) + g * sin(theta1) * cos(theta1 - theta2)) + m2 * L2 * theta2_dot**2 * sin(theta1 - theta2) * cos(theta1 - theta2)) / (L2 * (m1 + m2 * sin(theta1 - theta2)**2)))

    # Update the values using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method
    k1_theta1 = dt * dtheta1_dt
    k1_theta2 = dt * dtheta2_dt
    k1_theta1_dot = dt * dtheta1_dot_dt
    k1_theta2_dot = dt * dtheta2_dot_dt

    k2_theta1 = dt * (dtheta1_dt + 0.5 * k1_theta1_dot)
    k2_theta2 = dt * (dtheta2_dt + 0.5 * k1_theta2_dot)
    k2_theta1_dot = dt * (dtheta1_dot_dt + 0.5 * dtheta1_dot_dt)
    k2_theta2_dot = dt * (dtheta2_dot_dt + 0.5 * dtheta2_dot_dt)

    k3_theta1 = dt * (dtheta1_dt + 0.5 * k2_theta1_dot)
    k3_theta2 = dt * (dtheta2_dt + 0.5 * k2_theta2_dot)
    k3_theta1_dot = dt * (dtheta1_dot_dt + 0.5 * dtheta1_dot_dt)
    k3_theta2_dot = dt * (dtheta2_dot_dt + 0.5 * dtheta2_dot_dt)

    k4_theta1 = dt * (dtheta1_dt + k3_theta1_dot)
    k4_theta2 = dt * (dtheta2_dt + k3_theta2_dot)
    k4_theta1_dot = dt * (dtheta1_dot_dt + dtheta1_dot_dt)
    k4_theta2_dot = dt * (dtheta2_dot_dt + dtheta2_dot_dt)

    theta1_dot = theta1_dot + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta1_dot + 2.0 * k2_theta1_dot + 2.0 * k3_theta1_dot + k4_theta1_dot)
    theta2_dot = theta2_dot + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta2_dot + 2.0 * k2_theta2_dot + 2.0 * k3_theta2_dot + k4_theta2_dot)
    theta1 = theta1 + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta1 + 2.0 * k2_theta1 + 2.0 * k3_theta1 + k4_theta1)
    theta2 = theta2 + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta2 + 2.0 * k2_theta2 + 2.0 * k3_theta2 + k4_theta2)

    # Update time
    t = i * dt

    # Plot the double pendulum motion
    if (i == 1) {
        set xrange [-2:2]
        set yrange [-2:2]
        plot L1 * sin(theta1), -L1 * cos(theta1), L1 * sin(theta1) + L2 * sin(theta2), -L1 * cos(theta1) - L2 * cos(theta2) with lines title 'Pendulum 1', '' using 3:4 with lines title 'Pendulum 2'
    } else {
        replot
    }
    pause 0.01
}
```

I am using the gnuplot 5.4 Patch 8 and using 4th order Runge-Kutta method to solve the differential equations to the 2D model.

Here is a picture of the error. I don't know anymore what to do. I am not an expert in gnuplot. But I did some other things on it.

[image: ERROR]

Comment: You are not implementing RK4, you are implementing a very elaborate version of the Euler method.

Answer (score 2):

The error comes from your initial plot command, which is executed the first time through the loop.  Splitting your command onto multiple lines for readability, it is:

```
plot L1 * sin(theta1), \
    -L1 * cos(theta1), \
     L1 * sin(theta1) + L2 * sin(theta2), \
    -L1 * cos(theta1) - L2 * cos(theta2) with lines title 'Pendulum 1', \
    '' using 3:4 with lines title 'Pendulum 2'
```

The issue is the very last plot clause `'' using 3:4`.  The empty pair of quotes means "previous filename", but indeed there is no previous file name. It is not clear to me what you intended there, but `''` cannot work.

Do you maybe have a previous fit saved in a file somewhere and that's what you want to plot for comparison?  Put that file name inside the quotes.

Comment: Didn't work. I am not so good with it.

Comment: Which name I put there?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get your script running.
Actually, in my comment I was wrong: your thetas *are* functions of time, but your line `t=i*dt` is useless because `t` is used nowhere.

A few comments:

- use `set size ratio -1` to make x- and y-plot dimensions identical
- if your initial values `theta1_0, theta2_0, theta1_dot_0, theta2_dot_0` are all zero, nothing will move. So, at least one value should be unequal zero.
- if you want to draw the pendulum you better use the plotting style `with vectors` and if you want to plot the mass as well, additionally, the plotting style `with points`
- `plot '+' every ::::0` is used to [plot a single point (or vector)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19452516/7295599) in each iteration of the loop.

No warranty that the math is correct, I did not check this, but simply took it over from your script. At least, the output looks somehow reasonable.

**Script:**

```
### gif of double pendulum
reset session

# Constants
m1 = 1.0
m2 = 1.0
L1 = 1.0
L2 = 1.0
g  = 9.81

# Initial conditions
theta1_0 = 30.0
theta2_0 = 30.0
theta1_dot_0 = 1.0
theta2_dot_0 = 1.0

# Time
dt    = 0.02
t_max = 10.0

# Initial values of theta1, theta2, theta1_dot, and theta2_dot
theta1 = theta1_0
theta2 = theta2_0
theta1_dot = theta1_dot_0
theta2_dot = theta2_dot_0

# Set output file
set term gif size 400,400 animate delay 1 optimize
set output "SO76561252.gif"

set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]
set size ratio -1
set key noautotitle

# Numerical integration using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method
do for [i = 0:int(t_max / dt)] {

    # Calculate derivatives
    dtheta1_dt = theta1_dot
    dtheta2_dt = theta2_dot
    dtheta1_dot_dt = (m2 * g * sin(theta2) * cos(theta1 - theta2) - m2 * sin(theta1 - theta2) * (L1 * theta1_dot**2 * cos(theta1 - theta2) + L2 * theta2_dot**2) - (m1 + m2) * g * sin(theta1)) / (L1 * (m1 + m2 * sin(theta1 - theta2)**2))
    dtheta2_dot_dt = (( (m1 + m2) * (L1 * theta1_dot**2 * sin(theta1 - theta2) - g * sin(theta2) + g * sin(theta1) * cos(theta1 - theta2)) + m2 * L2 * theta2_dot**2 * sin(theta1 - theta2) * cos(theta1 - theta2)) / (L2 * (m1 + m2 * sin(theta1 - theta2)**2)))

    # Update the values using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method
    k1_theta1 = dt * dtheta1_dt
    k1_theta2 = dt * dtheta2_dt
    k1_theta1_dot = dt * dtheta1_dot_dt
    k1_theta2_dot = dt * dtheta2_dot_dt

    k2_theta1 = dt * (dtheta1_dt + 0.5 * k1_theta1_dot)
    k2_theta2 = dt * (dtheta2_dt + 0.5 * k1_theta2_dot)
    k2_theta1_dot = dt * (dtheta1_dot_dt + 0.5 * dtheta1_dot_dt)
    k2_theta2_dot = dt * (dtheta2_dot_dt + 0.5 * dtheta2_dot_dt)

    k3_theta1 = dt * (dtheta1_dt + 0.5 * k2_theta1_dot)
    k3_theta2 = dt * (dtheta2_dt + 0.5 * k2_theta2_dot)
    k3_theta1_dot = dt * (dtheta1_dot_dt + 0.5 * dtheta1_dot_dt)
    k3_theta2_dot = dt * (dtheta2_dot_dt + 0.5 * dtheta2_dot_dt)

    k4_theta1 = dt * (dtheta1_dt + k3_theta1_dot)
    k4_theta2 = dt * (dtheta2_dt + k3_theta2_dot)
    k4_theta1_dot = dt * (dtheta1_dot_dt + dtheta1_dot_dt)
    k4_theta2_dot = dt * (dtheta2_dot_dt + dtheta2_dot_dt)

    theta1_dot = theta1_dot + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta1_dot + 2.0 * k2_theta1_dot + 2.0 * k3_theta1_dot + k4_theta1_dot)
    theta2_dot = theta2_dot + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta2_dot + 2.0 * k2_theta2_dot + 2.0 * k3_theta2_dot + k4_theta2_dot)
    theta1 = theta1 + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta1 + 2.0 * k2_theta1 + 2.0 * k3_theta1 + k4_theta1)
    theta2 = theta2 + (1.0 / 6.0) * (k1_theta2 + 2.0 * k2_theta2 + 2.0 * k3_theta2 + k4_theta2)

    # Plot the double pendulum motion
    plot '+' every ::::0 u (0):(0):(x1=L1*sin(theta1)):(y1=-L1*cos(theta1))     w vec nohead lw 2 lc "red"  ti 'Pendulum 1', \
         '+' every ::::0 u (x1):(y1):(dx2=L2*sin(theta2)):(dy2=-L2*cos(theta2)) w vec nohead lw 2 lc "blue" ti 'Pendulum 2', \
         '+' every ::::0 u (x1):(y1)         w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "red", \
         '+' every ::::0 u (x1+dx2):(y1+dy2) w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "blue", \
}
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:** `SO76561252.gif`

I don't know why the GIF is moving so slowly (despite the minimum `delay 1`). In a different viewer the GIF is moving much faster compared to the browser.

**Edit:** it looks like if the delay is <20 ms, the animation speed in the browser will be slow, but with 20 ms it will be much faster. So, maybe 20 ms is some minimum delay?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After having the framework for the gif generation in the answer of theozh, it remains to correct the RK4 application. With the existing computations up to `k1`, a correct implementation of the Euler method is possible. The mixing-and-matching afterwards is wrong and partially non-sensical.

In a correct implementation, the accelerations or second derivatives are evaluated in every stage of the time step, at the current mid-point that is constructed from the offsets computed thus far. To put all that into a one-line formula would result in a horrible formula salad. It is better to implement the acceleration evaluation as function and call it with the current mid-point coordinates. This implements the formulas once to be called four times per time step.

Unfortunately, gnuplot is no Matlab or Python, here all user-defined functions are scalar. So if we can no re-use common intermediate values, then at least only implement the expressions once, resulting in a computational graph where each node is a scalar function of as many arguments as necessary. The accelerations result from a solution of a linear system for the second derivatives, see [Double Pendulum - First-order system from Lagrangian](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3931310/115115). So it makes some amount of sense to construct the entries of the system and then code Cramer's formulas on top of them.

Thus after "Constants" and before "Initial conditions" add a section

```python
# Acceleration functions and their building blocks
acc_a11 = mu
acc_a12(th1,th2) = cos(th1-th2)
acc_b1(th1,th2,dth2) = mu*g*L1*sin(th1) + L2*sin(th1-th2)*dth2**2
# acc_a21=cos(th1−th2) = a12
acc_a22=1
acc_b2(th1,th2,dth1) = g*L2*sin(th2) - L1*sin(th1-th2)*dth1**2

acc_den(th1,th2) = acc_a11*acc_a22 - acc_a12(th1,th2)**2
acc_num1(th1,th2,dth1,dth2) = acc_b1(th1,th2,dth2)*acc_a22 - acc_b2(th1,th2,dth1)*acc_a12(th1,th2)
acc_num2(th1,th2,dth1,dth2) = acc_a11*acc_b2(th1,th2,dth1) - acc_a12(th1,th2)*acc_b1(th1,th2,dth2)

theta1_ddot(th1,th2,dth1,dth2) = -acc_num1(th1,th2,dth1,dth2)/L1/acc_den(th1,th2) 
theta2_ddot(th1,th2,dth1,dth2) = -acc_num2(th1,th2,dth1,dth2)/L2/acc_den(th1,th2)
```

Then replace the time loop from "Calculate derivatives" to before the final combinations in the Simpson formulas with

```python
    # Calculate the increments or stages of the 4th order Runge-Kutta method
    k1_theta1 = dt * theta1_dot
    k1_theta2 = dt * theta2_dot
    k1_theta1_dot = dt * theta1_ddot(theta1,theta2,theta1_dot,theta2_dot)
    k1_theta2_dot = dt * theta2_ddot(theta1,theta2,theta1_dot,theta2_dot)
    
    th1_mid = theta1 + 0.5 * k1_theta1
    th2_mid = theta2 + 0.5 * k1_theta2
    th1_d_mid = theta1_dot + 0.5 * k1_theta1_dot
    th2_d_mid = theta2_dot + 0.5 * k1_theta2_dot

    k2_theta1 = dt * th1_d_mid
    k2_theta2 = dt * th2_d_mid
    k2_theta1_dot = dt * theta1_ddot(th1_mid,th2_mid,th1_d_mid,th2_d_mid)
    k2_theta2_dot = dt * theta2_ddot(th1_mid,th2_mid,th1_d_mid,th2_d_mid)

    th1_mid = theta1 + 0.5 * k2_theta1
    th2_mid = theta2 + 0.5 * k2_theta2
    th1_d_mid = theta1_dot + 0.5 * k2_theta1_dot
    th2_d_mid = theta2_dot + 0.5 * k2_theta2_dot

    k3_theta1 = dt * th1_d_mid
    k3_theta2 = dt * th2_d_mid
    k3_theta1_dot = dt * theta1_ddot(th1_mid,th2_mid,th1_d_mid,th2_d_mid)
    k3_theta2_dot = dt * theta2_ddot(th1_mid,th2_mid,th1_d_mid,th2_d_mid)

    th1_mid = theta1 + k3_theta1
    th2_mid = theta2 + k3_theta2
    th1_d_mid = theta1_dot + k3_theta1_dot
    th2_d_mid = theta2_dot + k3_theta2_dot

    k4_theta1 = dt * th1_d_mid
    k4_theta2 = dt * th2_d_mid
    k4_theta1_dot = dt * theta1_ddot(th1_mid,th2_mid,th1_d_mid,th2_d_mid)
    k4_theta2_dot = dt * theta2_ddot(th1_mid,th2_mid,th1_d_mid,th2_d_mid)
```

If that looks repetitive and boring, it helps to find errors visually by violations of the pattern, and also hints how this could be implemented as system with vector-valued functions of vector arguments. Then the RK4 implementation reduces back to its "cook-book" formulation that looks like the scalar case.

I changed `tmax=50` and `dt=0.05`

[image]

As the dynamic is in the angles only, and the original method is somewhat close to the Euler method, differences of the solutions are hard to evaluate from the solution. One would have to compare time-value graphs for different step sizes in both methods, or scaled differences of the values, to see the order of the methods and how accurate they are.